# Microsoft Viva learning set up with the existing SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-viva

As per the Microsoft documentation viva, learning can be set up with the below services or connections:

- **Microsoft Learn** – Microsoft’s own collection of learning content
  about its tools
- **LinkedIn Learning** – a huge source of learning and
  course material, previously branded as Lynda and now owned by
  Microsoft through the LinkedIn acquisition
- Leading course providers   including Skillsoft and Coursera
- The Learning Platform or LMS –   integrations are planned with Cornerstone OnDemand, Saba,
  SuccessFactors and more, and APIs will be made available later in
  2021 to enable other Learning Platforms to arrange integrations
- **SharePoint document libraries.**

We are interested in setting up the learning mechanism with our existing SharePoint Online site, however, when I was exploring the Viva learning with SharePoint site configuration, I didn't get any documentation or article in google, so if you come across any article/video/documentation or any other resources with respect to configuring the Viva learning with Sharepoint Online site, will be a great help for us.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer following articles to configure the Viva learning with SharePoint Online site.

[9 Steps to Prepare Your SharePoint Intranet for Microsoft Viva](https://pixelmill.com/9-steps-to-prepare-your-sharepoint-intranet-for-microsoft-viva/)

[Announcing Viva Learning public preview coming in April](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-viva-blog/announcing-viva-learning-public-preview-coming-in-april/ba-p/2167343)

Comment: Hi - I have already gone through these links, these are no specific to the SharePoint site with Viva learning, these are Viva learning generic links.

Comment: Here's another article for you. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-mechanics-blog/microsoft-viva-learning-personalized-learning-experience-through/ba-p/2422420